# Jquery / data filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display a few images based on the categories they fall in. Every image falls into more than one category. I have links above the images representing each of the categories, and the idea is that when people click one of the links the images in that category are displayed and the others are hidden.

I have the following code for the category links:

```
<a class="cat-title" href="#" data-filter="cat-102">Category name</a>
<a class="cat-title" href="#" data-filter="cat-2">Category name</a>
<a class="cat-title" href="#" data-filter="cat-17">Category name</a>
<a class="cat-title" href="#" data-filter="cat-151>Category name</a>
```

Then for the images:

```
<a data-tags="cat-2, cat-3, cat-17, cat-101, cat-102, cat-132, cat-151" href="link">
    <img src="src">
</a>
<a data-tags="cat-2, cat-102, cat-151" href="link">
    <img src="src">
</a>
```

etc.

Now the problem is I don't know a lot about jquery, but I tried Googling for help. The problem is that I would need to filter the images not only for one tag, but for more tags (so that the image displays if any of the categories it belongs to are selected). I wasn't able to find any example online of this situation.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow. But still I would like to help you. Check out [MixItUp](http://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) and they have the same thing what you need.

Comment: How do you 'unselect' categories? By clicking on the same link? Meaning: you have links, but maybe they should be `checkbox` buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$('.cat-title').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var filter = $(this).data('filter');

    $('[data-tags]')
        .hide()
        .filter('[data-tags*="' + filter + ',"],[data-tags$="' + filter + '"]')
        .show();  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b2cz2k6a/1/

Comment: That will filter cat-21, cat-22, cat-23, etc. when cat-filter will be cat-2.

Comment: Thanks; I used this and got it working, thumbs up, didn't realize it could be done so easily!

Answer (score 1):

Use classes instead of `data-tags`.

```
<a class="filtered-image cat-2 cat-3 cat-17 cat-101"><img src="src"></a>
```

Then when the user clicks on a filter, you can do:

```
$(".cat-title").click(function() {
    $(".filtered-image." + $(this).data("filter")).show();
    return false; // Prevent default link action
});
```

Comment: Any reason to create a new jQuery object with `$(this).data("filter")` when you can do `this.dataset.filter`? I see this often.

Comment: `.data()` caches the data, parses it as JSON, etc.

Comment: `.data()` also works on browser versions that don't implement `.dataset`.

Comment: Came to the same conclusion. Thanks for the precisions.